# jsx map inside if else condition

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a condition look like below

```js
{finishedTodos
? 
                <ListItem button divider className={classes.finishCategory} >
                <ArrowForward className={classes.checkIcon} />
                <ListItemText primary={`Finished      ${finishedTodos.length}`}  style={{color:"tomato"}}/>
                </ListItem>
                
: null }
//---------------------------------------------
        {finishedTodos.map((todo) =>(     
              <ListItem button divider>
                <CheckCircle className={classes.checkIcon} />
                <ListItemText primary={todo.title} style={{textDecoration:"line-through",color:"gray"}} />
              </ListItem>
        ))}
```

so right now what I want to do is I Want to combine these two , and when I tried to put {finishedTodos.map... below the `</ListItem>`,it reported ": expected" , so I think there's something wrong with formatting , do anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: what you mean by combine ?

Comment: One thing you can do that is slightly better is use the `&&` operator for the first condition. `{finishedTodos && <YourCompoents... /> }`

Comment: Probably because you were returning more than one element from the ternary. Move the mapping code back and wrap the whole block with a fragment (`<><ListItem>...{mapcode}</>`).

Comment: `{finishedTodos.map((todo) =>` is not in same escope. Try if - else if and else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX requires returned code blocks to be wrapped in a single JSX element, like a `<div>`. You can also use simple JSX fragments `<>...</>` to wrap your code.

In this case, I would also recommend using a *short circuit operator*, `&&`, instead of a *ternary operator* `? ... :null` for simple `if {}` statements.

```
{finishedTodos  &&
  <>
    <ListItem button divider className={classes.finishCategory} >
       <ArrowForward className={classes.checkIcon} />
       <ListItemText 
          primary={`Finished ${finishedTodos.length}`}  
          style={{color:"tomato"}}/>
    </ListItem>
    {finishedTodos.map((todo) => 
       <ListItem button divider>
          <CheckCircle className={classes.checkIcon} />
          <ListItemText 
             primary={todo.title} 
             style={{textDecoration:"line-through",color:"gray"}} />
       </ListItem>
     )}
  </>
}
```

Comment: I like that your answer provides some explanation as to *why* this is the fix. Some small improvements: Even though you put HTML in quotes, I'd call it what it is: JSX since the two are already confusing to new React devs, but are really very different. I woudn't recommend the short circuit operator for most situations because of how it handles some falsy values (ie if `finishedTodos` is `0`, it will actually render `0` instead of nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Just update like it with [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

```
{
  finishedTodos ? (
    <>
      <ListItem button divider className={classes.finishCategory}>
        <ArrowForward className={classes.checkIcon} />
        <ListItemText
          primary={`Finished      ${finishedTodos.length}`}
          style={{ color: "tomato" }}
        />
      </ListItem>
      {finishedTodos.map((todo) => (
        <ListItem button divider>
          <CheckCircle className={classes.checkIcon} />
          <ListItemText
            primary={todo.title}
            style={{ textDecoration: "line-through", color: "gray" }}
          />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </>
  ) : null;
}
```